# Where's the mistake in this calculation?

Tags: complex-numbers, multivalued-functions

Obviously something is wrong with this, but where is the error and why is it one?

$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{-1} &= (-1)^{1/2} \\
&= (-1)^{2/4} \\
&= \sqrt[4]{(-1)^2} \\
&= \sqrt[4]{1} \\
&= 1.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: The way you are using the laws of indeces is only valid for positive numbers.

Comment: Your last step is incorrect. The fourth root of $1$ has in fact four solutions in the complex plane: $+1$, $+i$, $-1$ and $-i$. Your initial value is indeed one of them.

Comment: This is because $\sqrt{-1}$ is imaginary, It is not there !! :D

An illusion !

Comment: With the same (wrong) reasoning, $-1=\sqrt[3]{-1}=(-1)^{1/3}=(-1)^{2/6}=\sqrt[6]{(-1)^2}=\sqrt[6]{1}=1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multivaluedness has been ignored at several steps, example $\sqrt{-1}=\pm i$.

In the language of complex analysis, you have to define
an appropriate branch of the square root function.

Comment: +1 correct, but it may be better to include a more basic explanation. People who understand this answer don't need it :-D

Comment: @Ant, I agree. will do so next time, thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

When the exponent is not an integer there may be more than one valid result of any exponentiation of a complex number.   In particular there are always two square roots, and four quaternary roots.   The square root of a square of a number is not necessarily that number.

${(a^2)}^{1/2} = \pm a$

$(r^2e^{2i\theta})^{1/2} = \lvert r\rvert e^{i(\theta+n\pi)} \;\mathbf 1_{n\in\Bbb Z}$

Answer (score 0):

Because there is more than one root of $1^{\frac{1}{4}}$.